# Paperjs - unable to clear raster

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am drawing rasters with a helper function as so:

```
 const icon = new Raster({
 source: getBase64Icon(source,
    position: new Point(x, y)
 });
 icon.scale(scale);
```

It does work and I get the icon at the right position in the right scale.
The problem is when I try to use the `clear()` method to clear a raster.
I even tried explicitly adding `icon.clear();` after the scaling and it doesn't work.
There are no errors, and logging to the console `icon.clear` does show a function code.

Maybe important to mention that these icons are drawn on a particular layer.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I guess your icon should not be declared as const if you modify it (with `icon.clear()`), you can use `let icon = new Raster(...);` instead.

Comment: Thanks @arthur.sw. Tried to change it to `let` and it still not clearing

Comment: Can you create a sketch on sketch.paper.js?

Comment: @arthur.sw, weirdly I can't reproduce it in a sketch. Thanks anyway, I will simply tackle my issue differently

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for the `item.remove()` method which takes the item out of the scene graph and thus makes it disappear.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.4/S/PVDBasMwDP0V4UtTCHYOPWV0p33BNuih3cFzReJ2lo2lNoySf5+d0AmEeDzp6UkPRTag6tXHFcWNqlUunis2Bt6yncAS+GAH1Kd8IheJBbJlwQx7IJzgfQHNo9JQguMtO+xhM4qk3hjLjMI62YT5wjrmwSx6bILN/ueX9CUNm/Y5niJ78ZF6uHuctEMq6pWcty+11CzWDtYL7ICxODqz1ou7sujTB4w3aZot7F/h31SZKD0yIkHGEO8IXvSTXM/RK9Gsa+YWdl3XraA85TujvaboSVj1x6/5Dw==) demonstrating the solution.

```js
// Draw an image.
const raster = new Raster({
    source: 'http://assets.paperjs.org/images/marilyn.jpg',
    position: view.center
});

// Wait 4 seconds...
setTimeout(() => {
    // ...then remove it.
    raster.remove();
}, 4000);
```